# How to create a new row using aggregation of two or more rows?

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I'm running on RStudio. So, I run a pretty big database, and run a code to get a new dataframe (`Results_Final_Status`) based on the columns that I want.

```
Results_Final_Status = Results_Final %>% 
  group_by(status) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(total=n()) %>%
  arrange(-total)`
```

| status | total |
| --- | --- |
| Finished | 7083 |
| +1 Lap | 3850 |
| Engine | 2011 |
| +2 Laps | 1593 |
| Accident | 1044 |

So my objective is to create a new dataframe, and aggregate "+1 Lap" and "+2 Lap" creating a new value "OTHER" and the total SUM of this two values is added in the total column.

I've tried the `mutate` function and the `case_when` function, but something is missing and I keep having errors on RStudio. I'm expecting a new dataframe, with this values somewhat aggregated in order to create a new table, so my visualization is easier to observe (otherwise I would have like 100 rows with different values and a lot of "total" values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a brute force method but you can append rows to your current dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)

Results_final <- tibble(status=c('Finished','+1 Lap','Engine', '+2 Laps','Accident'),
                        total=c(7083,3850,2011,1593,1044)
                        )

Results_final_status <- Results_final %>% 
  add_row(.data = data.frame(status='Other',
                             total=sum(Results_final$total[Results_final$status=='+1 Lap'|
                                                             Results_final$status=='+2 Laps'])))

Results_final_status
```